# How to take median of column values for NON DISTINCT time stamps only

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, xts, tidyr

I am trying to clean some tick data. My data is in long form. When I convert it to wide it shows
`Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows` . The Time column has timestamps for several days. The SYM column has stock symbols for many stocks.  This is my sample data:

```
dput(jojo)
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1459481850, 1459481850, 1459482302, 
1459482305, 1459482305, 1459482307, 1459482307, 1459482309, 1459482312, 
1459482312, 1459482314, 1459482314, 1459482316, 1459482316, 1459482317, 
1459482317, 1459482318, 1459482319, 1459482319, 1459482320), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta"), PRICE = c(1371.25, 1371.25, 
1373.95, 1373, 1373, 1373.95, 1373.95, 1373.9, 1374, 1374, 1374.15, 
1374.15, 1374, 1374, 1373.85, 1373.85, 1372.55, 1374.05, 1374.05, 
1374.15), SIZE = c(39, 58, 5, 4, 7, 20, 5, 10, 21, 179, 10, 100, 
98, 78, 14, 11, 30, 10, 11, 39), SYM = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B")), .Names = c("Time", "PRICE", "SIZE", "SYM"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to first find the same time stamps then take median of PRICE and SIZE for these timestamps, and replace these same time stamp rows with a single row containing median values of PRICE and SIZE in the dataset. But my code summarises the whole column rather than the same time stamp rows for a stock symbol. This is my attempt:

```
#Cleaning duplicate time stamps
tt<- jojo %>%group_by(SYM )%>% summarise(Time = ifelse(n() >= 2, median, mean))
#Making wide form
tt<-spread(tt, SYM, PRICE)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : Not a vector
```

Please suggest corrections. It would be nice if I can do the cleaning without using highfrequency package.

Comment: What is the expected output of the example you provided? The `Error: Not a vector` is because you do not define a variable for `median` and `mean`

Comment: I want to take median of PRICE and SIZE for duplicate time stamps for each stock.

Comment: sp `jojo %>% group_by(Time, SYM) %>% mutate(PRICE = median(PRICE), SIZE = median(SIZE)) %>% filter(duplicated(Time))` ?

Comment: @Sotos it should first find the same time stamps then take median of PRICE and SIZE for these timestamps, and replace these same time stamp rows with a single row containing median values of PRICE and SIZE in the dataset.

Comment: oh, ok so summarise instead of mutate (`jojo %>% group_by(Time, SYM) %>% summarise(PRICE = median(PRICE), SIZE = median(SIZE))`)

Comment: @Sotos ok. it works. But why not group_by(SYM, Time) instead of (Time, SYM). I need to delete common timestamps for a stock  rather than the ones common to  all stocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose whether you want to use the `dplyr` or `xts` paradigm. They do not play well together, mostly because `dplyr` expects data.frames and `xts` objects are matrices. `dplyr` also masks the `stats::lag` generic, which prevents method dispatch (e.g. so running `lag(.xts(1,1))` at the top-level will not do what you expect).

To solve this problem using the `xts` paradigm:

```
# create a function to convert to xts and take medians of the two columns
unDuplicate <- function(x) {
  # create xts object
  X <- xts(x[,c("PRICE","SIZE")], x[,"Time"])
  # set column names so they will be unique in wide format
  colnames(X) <- paste(colnames(X), x[1,"SYM"], sep = ".")
  # function to take median of each column
  colMedian <- function(obj, ...) {
    apply(obj, 2, median, ...)
  }
  # aggregate by seconds
  period.apply(X, endpoints(X, "seconds"), colMedian)
}
# now you can call the function on each symbol, then merge the results
do.call(merge, lapply(split(jojo, jojo$SYM), unDuplicate))
```

Comment: Please help I have a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317111/performing-previous-tick-aggregation-using-lapply-and-split