# performing previous tick aggregation using lapply and split

Tags: r, aggregate, xts, lapply

I am trying to solve this issue for past 3 months. Please help.

I have tick data (Price and Volume) for many stocks belonging to a single exchange. Each stock has its own `.rds` file on the hard disk. I am interested in cleaning it up:

1. merge multiple same time stamps by taking median
2. subset data for exchange hours only
3. aggregate it over 20 minutes by previous tick aggregation

I know that the

> function aggregatets in highfrequency package

can perform the previous tick aggregation operation. However, the function takes one stock one day data only.

To demonstrate the problem I am using raw tick data (named trade) for a single stock.

```
    dput(head(trade,50))
structure(c(54.7, 54.7, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.6, 54.6, 54.65, 
54.65, 54.6, 54.65, 54.65, 54.65, 54.65, 54.7, 54.7, 54.8, 54.8, 
54.85, 54.85, 54.85, 54.85, 54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.65, 54.65, 
54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.65, 54.65, 54.65, 54.75, 54.65, 54.7, 
54.7, 54.7, 54.75, 54.75, 54.75, 54.75, 54.75, 54.7, 54.7, 54.7, 
54.65, 54.65, 8, 542, 110, 600, 88, 200, 150, 100, 700, 250, 
75, 100, 25, 200, 100, 600, 1546, 940, 100, 6250, 89, 6911, 89, 
211, 100, 50, 1410, 1090, 913, 4737, 50, 300, 2486, 400, 25, 
85, 250, 168, 50, 100, 40, 40, 60, 50, 40, 10, 91, 6072, 229, 
1000), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", index = structure(c(1459481853, 
1459481853, 1459482302, 1459482302, 1459482305, 1459482306, 1459482306, 
1459482307, 1459482307, 1459482308, 1459482312, 1459482314, 1459482314, 
1459482315, 1459482317, 1459482317, 1459482318, 1459482318, 1459482319, 
1459482319, 1459482320, 1459482320, 1459482322, 1459482322, 1459482330, 
1459482330, 1459482331, 1459482331, 1459482336, 1459482336, 1459482337, 
1459482337, 1459482338, 1459482338, 1459482339, 1459482340, 1459482344, 
1459482348, 1459482351, 1459482351, 1459482356, 1459482357, 1459482357, 
1459482361, 1459482362, 1459482364, 1459482367, 1459482367, 1459482369, 
1459482369), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), .Dim = c(50L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("value", "size"
)))
```

I use the following code to do previous tick aggregation to 20 minute intervals:

```
require(xts)
require(highfrequency)
trade<-xts(trade[,-1], order.by = trade[,1])
trade2<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade,"days"), mergeTradesSameTimestamp))
colnames(trade)[c(1,2)]<-c("PRICE", "SIZE")
trade2<-trade2["T09:30:00/T15:30:00"]
trade2<-trade2[,1]
fundo=function(x) aggregatets(FUN = previoustick,on="minutes",k=20, dropna =F)
```

## As aggregatets() only takes data for 1 day I am splitting trade2 into days and apply it on them

```
trade3<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade2, "days"), fundo))
```

But I get the error for function `aggregatets`:

```
    trade3<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade2, "days"), fundo))
Error in FUN != "previoustick" : 
  comparison (2) is possible only for atomic and list types
Called from: aggregatets(FUN = previoustick, on = "minutes", k = 20, dropna = F)
```

Please suggest how to solve this error.

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible by re-doing it with some sample data?

Comment: @Konrad I have added some data please see.

Comment: You are making references to files and file name list that will fail `all.stocks.list<-list(); listofnames<- list.files(pattern="*.rds"); for(Q in 1:length(listofnames))` without those files availble. It would be easier for folk to engage with the question if you redo it so it can be copied and pasted to R script. Side point, the function is trivial: `highfrequency::previoustick`, returns last element of `a`. I'm guessing that is being passed to it does not lend itself well for the simple operation. Look at the *class* of the passed objects and try     `a = as.vector(a); b = a[length(a)]`.

Comment: @Konrad Please see the code I have used that produced the error. Please elaborate on the also sidepoint. Thanks

Comment: `split(trade2, "days")` produces an error; there is no usable object passed to `aggregates`.

Comment: @Konrad please try again. I have made same edits after being able to use  mergeTradesSameTimestamp with lapply and split. But I am still not able to use aggregatets .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works, based on the limited data you provided.  Your error was from not passing though an object to argument `ts`.  (Also in your sample data, none of the ticks happened before 9:30am, so for reproducibility of this answer I changed it to 8.30am. i.e. `trade2<-trade2["T08:30:00/T15:30:00"]`):

```
trade <- structure(c(54.7, 54.7, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.6, 54.6, 54.65, 
    54.65, 54.6, 54.65, 54.65, 54.65, 54.65, 54.7, 54.7, 54.8, 54.8, 
    54.85, 54.85, 54.85, 54.85, 54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.65, 54.65, 
    54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.8, 54.65, 54.65, 54.65, 54.75, 54.65, 54.7, 
    54.7, 54.7, 54.75, 54.75, 54.75, 54.75, 54.75, 54.7, 54.7, 54.7, 
    54.65, 54.65, 8, 542, 110, 600, 88, 200, 150, 100, 700, 250, 
    75, 100, 25, 200, 100, 600, 1546, 940, 100, 6250, 89, 6911, 89, 
    211, 100, 50, 1410, 1090, 913, 4737, 50, 300, 2486, 400, 25, 
    85, 250, 168, 50, 100, 40, 40, 60, 50, 40, 10, 91, 6072, 229, 
    1000), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", index = structure(c(1459481853, 
    1459481853, 1459482302, 1459482302, 1459482305, 1459482306, 1459482306, 
    1459482307, 1459482307, 1459482308, 1459482312, 1459482314, 1459482314, 
    1459482315, 1459482317, 1459482317, 1459482318, 1459482318, 1459482319, 
    1459482319, 1459482320, 1459482320, 1459482322, 1459482322, 1459482330, 
    1459482330, 1459482331, 1459482331, 1459482336, 1459482336, 1459482337, 
    1459482337, 1459482338, 1459482338, 1459482339, 1459482340, 1459482344, 
    1459482348, 1459482351, 1459482351, 1459482356, 1459482357, 1459482357, 
    1459482361, 1459482362, 1459482364, 1459482367, 1459482367, 1459482369, 
    1459482369), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), .Dim = c(50L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("value", "size"
    )))

# mergeTradesSameTimestamp wants "PRICE" column, so rename now:
colnames(trade) <- c("PRICE", "SIZE")

trade2<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade,"days"), mergeTradesSameTimestamp))
trade2<-trade2["T08:30:00/T15:30:00"]
# Your error was from not passing through x to argument ts:
fundo=function(x) aggregatets(ts = x, FUN = "previoustick",on="minutes",k=20, dropna =F)
trade3<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade2, "days"), fundo))
```

Comment: Can we use aggregateTrades() instead of aggregatets()?

Comment: @runjumpfly I don't understand what you're asking by this.  `lapply` can take any function that makes sense.  Just update `fundo` accordingly in your case.

Comment: fundo=function(x) aggregateTrades(tdata = x, FUN ="previoustick",on="minutes",k=20,marketopen = "09:15:00", marketclose = "15:30:00") 
trade3<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(trade2, "days"), fundo))
 produces Error in dimnames(cd) <- list(as.character(index(x)), colnames(x)) : 
'dimnames' applied to non-array